# How can I control this response coming from C# backend project?

Tags: c#, angular, postman, bad-request

This is my first question here so I am very excited. :)

I am developing a car rental project with C# for backend and Angular for front end. When I try to register a new user with data of an existing user, I get attached response in Postman. The controller in backend sends a Badrequest with a message "User already exists!". I tried to control this at Front End side in Angular. What I would like to do is, just to recognize this error with an IF statement and show this message "User already exists!" on the web page with a toastr service. However, I can not detect it in Angular at all. Can you please help me? How can I take this backend response into control in Angular? Thanks in advance for your help!

Code in Controller:

```
[HttpPost("register")]
    public ActionResult Register(UserForRegisterDto userForRegisterDto)
    {
        var userExists = _authService.CheckIfUserExists(userForRegisterDto.Email);
        if (!userExists.Success)
        {
            return BadRequest(userExists.Message);
        }

        var registerResult = _authService.Register(userForRegisterDto, userForRegisterDto.Password);
        var result = _authService.CreateAccessToken(registerResult.Data);
        if (result.Success)
        {
            return Ok(result.Data);
        }

        return BadRequest(result.Message);
    }
```

Comment: Side note: "400 Bad Request" doesn't look like an appropriate response in either of the places that you're returning it. A bad request is one in which the input was malformed and couldn't be used. Rather, you were able to do something with the request, even if the result was not what was expected.

Comment: Can you please provide the message you are getting (on postman)? ASP.NET should be formatting the `result.Message` nicely for you there...

Comment: The message I get on Postman : User already exists!

It comes from "return BadRequest(userExists.Message);" because userExists holds an Error Result with a custom message (User already exists!) created by me.

Answer (score 0):

To return a specific response code with a message from backend:

`return new HttpStatusCodeResult(errorCode, "Message");`

Make sure the method in the controller is type ActionResult, not ViewResult.